# Is it a good design that EventExecutor extends EventExecutorGroup in netty?

Tags: java, netty

There are symbols of the two classes:

```
/**
 * The {@link EventExecutor} is a special {@link EventExecutorGroup} which comes
 * with some handy methods to see if a {@link Thread} is executed in a event loop.
 * Besides this, it also extends the {@link EventExecutorGroup} to allow for a generic
 * way to access methods.
 *
 */
public interface EventExecutor extends EventExecutorGroup {  

/**
 * The {@link EventExecutorGroup} is responsible for providing the {@link EventExecutor}'s to use
 * via its {@link #next()} method. Besides this, it is also responsible for handling their
 * life-cycle and allows shutting them down in a global fashion.
 *
 */
public interface EventExecutorGroup extends ScheduledExecutorService, Iterable<EventExecutor> {
```

The `EventExecutorGroup` is the container of the `EventExecutor` and manage their life-cycle. It's ok and easy to understand.

I think the design purpose is mainly to reuse some method definitions and feel not so natural. No one would make `Thread extends ThreadPool`, right?(emmmm.. There is `EventLoop` extends `EventLoopGroup` too....)

Why an element extends its container and treated itself as a special container?

I want to know if there are some advantages that I have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically as and `EventExecutor` is just `EventExecutorGroup` that only contains itself. Also this allows to re-use an `EventExecutor` where you are required to pass and `EventExecutorGroup`.

This comes in handy in many different situations like for example it allows you to create a `Bootstrap` and use one `EventLoop` as its `EventLoopGroup` and so ensure all the I/O is handled by the same thread. This is super useful for example when you build a proxy.

Comment: So in this way seems it eliminates the requirement of a single group wrapper class and makes the code cleaner.